# NSDate is older than today

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I understand how to compare two `NSDate` objects, e.g:

```
if ([olderDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    // do something

}
```

However I would like to just compare date components, not time since time can make the comparison inaccurate in my case.

**Is it possible to just compare day, month and year?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since iOS 8, `NSCalendar` has a number of convenience methods for this sort of comparison.

For example, there's:

```
- (NSDate *)startOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)date NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```

You can get the start of a given day from a date (such as `[NSDate date]` for "now") and then compare against that.

There's also:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareDate:(NSDate *)date1 toDate:(NSDate *)date2 toUnitGranularity:(NSCalendarUnit)unit NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```

You can call that with granularity `NSCalendarUnitDay` to do the comparison you want directly.

There are others, too. See NSCalendar.h for the details, since these methods don't seem to be in the class reference documentation, yet.

Comment: `- (NSComparisonResult)compareDate:(NSDate *)date1 toDate:(NSDate *)date2 toUnitGranularity:(NSCalendarUnit)unit NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);` worked perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can get  date component in this way

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:yourDate];
```

Then you can compare

```
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
if ([olderDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
  // do something
}
```